# How to use text operators in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

how do I use text operators on VBA? I would like to remove all "REP ??????" from excel. I tried "*REP*" but it didnt work. Thank you!

```
Sub test()

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

If Cells(i, 2) = "REP" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the left 3 characters:

```
Sub test()

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

If Left$(Cells(i, 2).Value, 3) = "REP" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that this is case sensitive.

Comment: Rory, how do I change to check 1st letter? Thank you.

Comment: `If Left$(Cells(i, 2).Value, 1) = "R" Then` for example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to compare a string to a cell. `Cell` is an object in VBA that has a `.Value` property. You need to compare the cell's *value* to "REP".

```
If Cells(i, 2).Value = "REP" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

@Rory's answer is correct if the cell value might only *start* with "REP" rather than that being the entire text. Notice that he also uses the `Left` function on the cell's value, not the cell itself.